# Read::read_to_end ignores whitespace when reading markdown

Tags: rust, iron

My function is as follows:

```
fn read_file () -> String {
  let mut file = File::open("./assets/postdata/lorem_ipsum.md").unwrap();
  let mut buffer = Vec::new();
  let read_variable = file.read_to_end(&mut buffer).unwrap();
  let filestr = String::from_utf8(buffer).unwrap();

  return filestr;
}
```

The file is a markdown file with four paragraphs of lorem ipsum text. This function, when called by a handlebars record generator, prints to a webpage producing a wall of text. I'm obviously missing something; how can I make the Rust compiler recognise the whitespace?

Comment: This sounds like it's unrelated to Rust or Iron: if all you're doing is dumping Markdown into HTML, then paragraph breaks won't show because HTML doesn't interpret newlines (outside of preformatted text elements).  `read_to_end` absolutely does not "ignore" whitespace or anything else.

Comment: I tried adding </br> to each newline, but all it did was show the tags. Is there another workaround?

Comment: Did you set the `Content-Type` header to `text/html`?

Comment: Have you tried replacing `read_to_end` with a hard coded chunk of data? Something like `fn read_file() -> String { "hello\nworld\nI\nam\ntext".into() }`.  You might as well use `read_to_string` as it combines two of your lines. `read_to_end`  isn't part of the Rust *compiler*. This is just part of the *standard library*.

Comment: It was actually an issue with Handlebars-rust and not interpreting the string correctly. Thanks everyone for your suggestions.